# Redmine setup LDAP failed (Invalid LDAP Account/Password)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, redmine

I have Redmine (3.4.6) setup on Centos 6.
Now, I want to use LDAP (connect to my AD)
Here is my configuration:

-Name: AD

-host: mydomain.com

-Port: 3268

-User: mydomain.com/administrator

-Pass: 12345678

-Base DN: dc=com,dc=mydomain

-Login: sAMAccountName

-FirstName: Name

-LastName:

-Email: UserPrincipalName

---

After that, when I tried testing connection, Redmine push an arlert  **(Invalid LDAP Account/Password)**

I can sure that my user and password are correct (I used in zimbra LDAP)

I need your hand to solve this problem! Thank

Answer (score 0):

Must change User to administrator@mydomain.com and it will be successful

Answer (score 0):

In case of Redmine integration with FreeIPA/LDAP I managed to

establish an authentication with the settings

that you can find in the screenshot below:

[image: Redmine integration with FreeIPA]

You can read more about this topic by navigating the page:

https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineLDAP